# expdp table with specific columns

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, expdp

I have a table in my database with 100 columns.

I am only interested to create a dump using expdp with only 3 specific columns from it.

Is it possible to do this directly from the expdp command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle 12c has a [datapump feature](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-data-pump-export-utility.html#GUID-E4E45E81-5391-43BE-B27D-B763EF79A885) `views_as_table` that may work. Create a view against your source table, with just the columns you want to export, then export the view:

```
create or replace view view_1 as 
  select <desired columns> from table_1;

expdp user/password views_as_tables=view_1 directory=data_pump_dir dumpfile=data.dmp
```